# Facebook-login dependency 4.27.0 can't be added with android SDK version 26.+

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, facebook-login

I was integrating facebook login with my android application and while adding facebook-login dependency version 4.27.0, android studio is generating following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"                                                                                       minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 26

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
```

Comment: read and search `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to`

Comment: Kindly see the answer and accept if it works for you. Because it worked for me for the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste this code at the end of your build.gradle (Module: app) file.

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.+'
        }
    }
}}
```